# Show/hide forms based on button id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a button for each form; when the users click on it, the specific form with the specific id will show or hide again.

I already tried the below JavaScript code, but it doesn't work.

Is this code wrong or do I miss something? Does someone have another idea?
Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.form2').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 
$result_posts = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_topic=:post_topic ORDER BY DATE(post_date) ASC");
$result_posts -> bindParam(':post_topic',$topic_id);
$result_posts -> execute();
while ($row2 = $result_posts ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
?>

<a class="btn" id="<?php echo $row2['post_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i>Comment</a>

<form name="form2" class="form2" id=" <?php echo $row2['post_id']; ?>" style="display:none">
<textarea class="commenting" id="commenting" placeholder="Comment here..." cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="comment_submit2" value="Submit" >
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You haven't included jQuery in your snippet - are you including it in your page? Consider editing your PHP/HTML code to instead be a small HTML snippet that accurately represents the output.

Comment: I am using "jquery-3.1.0.min.js"

Comment: Are you loading your form via ajax? I can't see any problem in your code abow, it should work.

Comment: Yes the form submiting executing via ajax.

Comment: If you load your form view via ajax, the javascript used to register click event on `.btn` must be execute after the request complete and appened to html document. Or you must change the target to listen which existing in your html document onload: `$(document).on('click', '.btn', handlerFunction)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to use `toggle()`:-

***Working example:-***

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btn',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.form2').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn"><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i>Comment</a>

<form name="form2" class="form2" style="display:none">
<textarea class="commenting" id="commenting" placeholder="Comment here..." cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="comment_submit2" value="Submit" >
</form>

<br>
<br>
<a class="btn"><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i>Comment</a>

<form name="form2" class="form2" style="display:none">
<textarea class="commenting" id="commenting" placeholder="Comment here..." cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="comment_submit2" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Note:- take care that no id will repeat in any case(in your code it's happening for button id and it's corresponding form id).

I had removed id's from button as well as from forms in my code . (if needed then try to make them different for each one )

Comment: the person who -ve marked, can you please tell why?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with jQuery, showing more than one form. The first form content shows by default.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("form").css("display","none");
        var TargetDiv = $(this).attr("data-target");
        $("#" + TargetDiv).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" data-target="form1">Form 1</button>
<button class="btn" data-target="form2">Form 2</button>
<button class="btn" data-target="form3">Form 3</button>

<form id="form1" style="display: block;">
    <label>show form one content by default</label>
</form>
<form id="form2" style="display: none;">
    <label>form two content</label>
</form>
<form id="form3" style="display: none;">
    <label>form three content</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should not repeate the ID in same document.  I can notice you will have button and form id same.

So what you can do concat some string with `post_id` like for button

> "btn_" + post_id

and for post something like -

> "form_" + post_id

use the toggel so it will inverse the state of form on each click.  If hidden it will be visible, and if visible on click it will be hidden.

Check my fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/crrwa7Ls/